# simple issue in implementing rating and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a very simple problme here, but somehow not able to get through this as i very little idea on jquery

I am using this piece of code to implement a rating function

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=440

Everything is working fine, but then i noticed once anyone clicked on any star, it can not change the rating.

**Here is the code**

**to build a array of stars**

```
<p>
    <img src="Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="1" />
    <img src="Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="2" />
    <img src="Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="3" />
    <img src="Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="4" />
    <img src="Images/EmptyStar.png" alt="Star Rating" align="middle" id="5" />
</p>
```

**The JS PART**

```
$("img").mouseover(function() {
    giveRating($(this), "FilledStar.png");
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
    giveRating($(this), "EmptyStar.png");
});
```

//-------

```
function giveRating(img, image) {            
    img.attr("src", "Images/" + image).prevAll("img").attr("src", "Images/" + image);
}
```

Now once anyone click on any stars the click event gets into action and do unbinding as follows:

```
$("img).click(function () {
    $(img).unbind("mouseout mouseover click");
});
```

What i am looking that even if someone clicked any start, he should be able to change it again either selecting higher or lesser rating

If anyone can guide me this simple thing, it will be highly appriciated

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts

Comment: First step would be to not remove the event bindings after you rate it once.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but in that case stars are not getting filled up, as moment mouse is moved, mouseover gets fired

Answer (score 0):

First remove this:

```
$(img).unbind("mouseout mouseover click");
```

Also you have to store the rating and restore it after you moved out...

```
function giveRating(img, image) {            
    img.attr("src", "Images/" + image).prevAll("img").attr("src", "Images/" + image);
    img.parent().get(0).rating = img;
}
```

...

Sorry, I am to leasy to finish this. Maybe some else will?

Or have a look at http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

There are many ready to use solutions for this.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but in that case stars are not getting filled up, as moment mouse is moved, mouseover gets fired